# HTML5 Video not playing on Safari Mobile

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I am trying to implement a background video as a landing page for a website however everything is working on all browsers except for Safari on Mobile devices.

website: http://www.ayushlal.com.au/VOS_Films

I am running iOS 13.6 (latest iOS version, not too sure what Safari version that is on my device)

Here is the HTML code:

```html
        <video loop muted controls playsinline autoplay preload="auto" src="assets/video/VOS_welcome.mp4">
            <source src="assets/video/VOS_welcome.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        </video>
```

The .mp4 file is roughly 60MB and has not been compressed as of yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue some time ago. Have you tried to set controls='true'? It worked for me. By default without setting a value, the controls are false.

Answer (score 0):

issue was to do with Low Power mode. Once disabled, video started playing perfectly fine.